# Deserializing date/time in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB to manage the communication with MongoDB instance. I have a simple document class containing id and `Instant` fields:

```
@Document
data class Test(
    @MongoId(FieldType.STRING)
    override var id: UUID,
    override val updatedAt: Instant,
)
```

An instance of this document is serialized into Mongo as (or actually showed in the Mongo shell as)

```
  {
    _id: '7ea1a5ff-0c3c-451f-9ebd-99def53541f5',
    updatedAt: ISODate('2023-10-09T11:43:51.152Z'),
  }
```

When used in the Spring app the deserialization works without issues. However, for testing purposes, I would also like to read documents from stored JSON files. The JSON serialization looks like this:

```
  {
    "_id": "c11f01c3-24a8-4321-a0ce-beb041207e5b",
    "updatedAt": {
      "$date": "2024-03-04T13:53:01.658Z"
    },
  }
```

I'm using the Spring-configured `ObjectMapper` instance for deserializing this (I assume the same instance that is used in the app), so I would expect that everything works as expected. However, apparently the `ObjectMapper` isn't aware of the MongoDB-specifics so the deserialization fails with

```
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.Instant` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

How to configure the `ObjectMapper` to properly handle MongoDB dates/times?

Note: The exact way how I'm reading the test data is this:

```
    @Bean
    fun repositoryPopulator(objectMapper: ObjectMapper) =
        Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean().apply {
            setMapper(objectMapper)
            setResources(paths)
        }
```

This is in a config class imported into `@SpringBootTest` so that's why I assume that the `ObjectMapper` instance should be the same as in the main app. But apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution is that you have to add the following annotation over your `Test` class property `updatedAt`

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", timezone = "UTC")
```

After that the following code will work:

```
    private static void jsonParserInstantTest() {
        Instant time = Instant.now();
        InstantHolder instantHolder = new InstantHolder();
        instantHolder.setCurrentTime(time);
        instantHolder.setId("test");
        try {

            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
            String serialized = om.writeValueAsString(instantHolder);

            System.out.println(serialized);

            InstantHolder restored = om.readValue(serialized, InstantHolder.class);

            System.out.println(restored);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

The output of this will be:

```
{"id":"test","currentTime":"2024-03-05T18:23:47.162Z"}
InstantHolder{id='test', currentTime=2024-03-05T18:23:47.162Z}
```

The `InstantHolder` class that I used is a very simple one:

```
    package com.mgnt.stam;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
    
    import java.time.Instant;
    
    public class InstantHolder {
        private String id;
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", timezone = "UTC")
        private Instant currentTime;

// Getter and setter methods are trivial and are omitted here to save space    

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "InstantHolder{" +
                    "id='" + id + '\'' +
                    ", currentTime=" + currentTime +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

So this provides a solution. But I can offer you a slight optimization where you don't have to instantiate and configure `ObjectMapper` class. Consider the client code like this:

```
private static void jsonParserInstantTest() {
    Instant time = Instant.now();
    InstantHolder instantHolder = new InstantHolder();
    instantHolder.setCurrentTime(time);
    instantHolder.setId("test");
    try {

        String serialized = JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(instantHolder);

        System.out.println(serialized);

        InstantHolder restored = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(serialized, InstantHolder.class);

        System.out.println(restored);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This will work exactly the same. However, you can see here the use of static methods of class `JsonUtils`. This class is a thin wrapper over ObjectMapper class and it comes as part of MgntUtils Open source library (written and maintained by me). Here is [Javadoc for JsonUtils class](https://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The library can be obtained as [a Maven artifact from Maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) as a jar file as well as Javadoc and source code

Comment: Your solution would also change the way how my document class is serialized into DB and I don't want to do that. I simply want to "manually" reverse the serializing process, e.g. I want to keep the DB content (with the `$date` wrapper), export it to JSON, and then somehow deserialize it back to the original document class.

Comment: My solution will not change the way that your date is serialized in DB. Just like I said in my answer, if you apply the annotation to the property `updatedAt` in your `Test` class everything will stay in the same format. I provided my own `InstantHolder` class just for example purposes.

Comment: I'm confused by your example `{"id":"test","currentTime":"2024-03-05T18:23:47.162Z"}
InstantHolder{id='test', currentTime=2024-03-05T18:23:47.162Z}`. If you are able to deserialize `InstantHolder` from the JSON with a scalar `currentTime` property, how come you are also able to deserialize (with the same config) from the JSON with an object (with the `$date` key) property?

Comment: I provided InstantHolder class as an example only, to demonstrate how to deserialize Instant property from a String value. In my opinion, if you copy the annotation that I provided in the InstantHolder class over the property currentTime to your Test class over the property updatedAt you should be able to resolve your issue